# Import error requires h5py

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, h5py

i have the below error while running my code on amazon ec2 instance and when trying to import the h5py package i have permission denied error
ImportError: `load_weights` requires h5py

Answer (score 0):

just solve it using sudo pip install hypy.